Quotient of polynomial ring over integers by maximal ideal is a finite field using Chevalley's Theorem
I want to make a quick proof of the following fact using the Chevalley's Theorem (if it's possible):

If $m$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, then ${\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]} / {m}$ is a finite field.

I will remind you the Chevalley's Theorem too:

Chevalley's Theorem. If $\pi: X \to Y$ is a finite type morphism of Noetherian schemes, then the image of any constructible set is constructible.

My idea is to consider the obvious map $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and take the prime ideal $\varphi^{-1}(m)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, which must be of the form $(p)$ for $p$ prime or $(0)$.
Firstly, I don't know what to do in the second case.
Considering the first case, I believe that the diagonal arrow in the next commutative diagram may help:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{F}_p & \rightarrow & {\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]} / {m}\\\
\downarrow & \nearrow\\\
\mathbb{F}_p[x_1,\dots,x_n]
\end{array}$$
Secondly, I can't finish this and I am quite sure that it's all wrong.
My question: How can one improve my argument or suggest another proof using the Chevalley's Theorem.
(Note that I'm not interested in proofs not using it, that are a lot on MSE).

$\varphi^{-1}(m)$ can't be $(0)$. Let's rule this out. If $\varphi^{-1}(m)=(0)$, we get an injection $\Bbb Z \hookrightarrow \Bbb Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/m$. This induces a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/m) \to \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z)$. Since $\Bbb Z \hookrightarrow \Bbb Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/m$ is injective, this morphism is dominant. And as the image consists of a single point (As $\Bbb Z[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/m$ is a field), the image must be the generic point. Now we prove the following lemma:
Lemma 1: Let $A$ be a PID with infinitely many prime ideals (or more generally, a domain which is not a Goldmann domain). Then the singleton containing the generic point $\{(0)\} \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is not constructible.
Suppose that $\{(0)\}=U \cap V$ with $U$ open and $V$ closed. Because $(0) \in V$ and $(0)$ is generic, we need to have that $V=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, thus $U \cap V=U$ and it suffices to show that the generic point is not open. Suppose that $(0)$ is an open point. Then passing to an distinguished affine open (and thus localizing $A$), we may suppose that $\{(0)\}=D(f)$ for some $f \in A$. But note that our assumptions imply that the integral domain $A_f$ is not a field and hence $|D(f)|=|\mathrm{Spec}(A_f)|>1$, a contradiction.
Using the lemma again, we can also finish the proof: Consider the induced morphism $\Bbb F_p \to \Bbb Z[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/m$. It suffices to show that the image of each $x_i$ in $\Bbb Z[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/m$ is algebraic. If not, then $\Bbb F_p[x] \hookrightarrow \Bbb Z[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/m$ sending $x$ to $x_i+m$ is injective and hence we get a dominant morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/m) \to \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb F_p[x])$. Again the image must be the generic point, which is not constructible by lemma 1, contradicting Chevalley's theorem.

To put this into more general context: there's a generalized version of Zariski's lemma and the Nullstellensatz for Jacobson schemes. As it turns out, at least in the (locally) Noetherian case, one can also deduce this more general theorem from Chevalley's theorem. I will refer to the stacks project for elementary topological lemmas.
Let's start with some definitions.
Definition 2: For a topological space $X$, we denote by $X_0$ the subspace consisting of closed points in $X$.
Definition 3: A topological space $X$ is called Jacobson if $X_0$ is very dense in $X$, that is, for every closed subset $Z \subseteq X$, we have $\overline{Z \cap X_0}=Z$.
Lemma 4: Let $X$ be a topological space and let $X=\bigcup_i U_i$ an open cover. Then $X$ is Jacobson iff each $U_i$ is Jacobson. In that case, we have $X_0=\bigcup_{i} U_{i,0}$
Proof: [stacks 005W]
Lemma 5: Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme and let $x \in X$. Then $x$ is locally closed if and only if $x$ is constructible.
Proof: Follows from [stacks 005L].
Lemma 6: Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme. Then the following are equivalent:

$X$ is Jacobson.
Every constructible point of $X$ is closed.

Proof: Suppose $X$ is Jacobson. If $x \in X$ is constructible, then by lemma 5 it is locally closed. Thus there is an open subset $U \subset X$ such that $x \in U_0$. But using lemma 4 again, we see that this implies that $x$ is closed in $X$.
Suppose that $X$ is not Jacobson. We may assume (using lemma 4) that $X$ is Noetherian. As $X$ is not Jacobson, there is some closed subset $Z \subseteq X$ such that $\overline{Z \cap X_0} \subsetneq Z$. Now $U:=Z \setminus \overline{Z \cap X_0}$ is an open subscheme of $Z$. As $Z$ is Noetherian, $U$ is quasicompact, thus it contains a closed point. This point is constructible in $X$, but by construction, it is not closed in $X$.
With this work done, we can finally come to the generalization of Zariski's lemma and Hilbert's Nullstellensatz I promised.
Theorem: Let $Y$ be a locally Noetherian Jacobson scheme and let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of locally finite type. Then:

$X$ is Jacobson.
$f$ maps closed points to closed points.
For every closed point $x \in X$, the extension of residue fields $\kappa(x)/\kappa(f(x))$ is of finite degree.

Proof: We may assume that $Y$ is Noetherian and affine, $f$ is of finite type (so $X$ is Noetherian) and that $X$ is affine. If $x \in X$ is constructible, then by Chevalley's theorem $f(x)$ is constructible, thus $f(x)$ is closed (lemma 6). This means that the composition $\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa(x)) \to X \xrightarrow{f} Y$ is a closed immersion. As everything is affine $f$ is seperated, so this implies that $\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa(x)) \to X$ is a closed immersion, i.e. that $x \in X$ is closed. Thus lemma 6 implies $X$ is Jacobson.
The second part follows from the first part, lemma 4, lemma 6 and Chevalley's theorem by reducing to the Noetherian case.
For the third part, assume everything is affine again, $X=\mathrm{Spec}(B), Y=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Then $x$ is a maximal ideal in $A$, so $\kappa(x)=B/x$. Thus $\kappa(x)$ is of finite type over $A$ and hence over $\kappa(f(x))$. Thus it suffices that every element of $\kappa(x)$ is algebraic over $\kappa(f(x))$. This can be done by lemma 1 just as before: If $\alpha \in \kappa(x)$ is transcendental over $\kappa(f(x))$, then this leads to an injection $\kappa(f(x))[T] \hookrightarrow \kappa(x)$, which implies by Chevalley that the generic point in $\Bbb A^1_{\kappa(f(x))}$ is constructible which it isn't be lemma 1.
(Remark: We can omit the locally Noetherian condition in the statement of the theorem and it is still true, although then we need a different proof.)
